# how to clearInterval at the same time as declaring another

Tags: javascript

i got this function setInterval every 2 seconds inside there are 2 other setIntervals with if statements , basicly i want to to enlarge an image every 2 seconds and when it reaches a specific width i want it to clear the interval and run another setInterval this time minimizing the image.

it works but not so clear , i mean that it will work but it could run the same intervals at the same time it could get bigger and than smaller like the image gone mad
function question2() {

```
setInterval(function () {
    var check = true;
    var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
    var imgW = img2.width;
    if (check)
        img2.style.width = (imgW + 20) + "px";
    else
        img2.style.width = (imgW - 20) + "px";
    if (imgW >= 240 || imgW<200)
        check = false;


}, 200);
    }

question2();
```

Comment: You basically have one interval coordinating two other intervals?! You could just do that with only one interval: If width is below a certain size, add to it, otherwise, subtract from it. That's all. No need to start separate intervals to do the resizing.

Comment: but how would it know when to stop enlarging? i need to set a clearInterval command

Comment: if i write it like this..
function question2() {

    setInterval(function () {
        var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
        if (img2.width <= 100)
            img2.setAttribute("width", img2.width + 10);
        if (img2.width >= 240)
            img2.setAttribute("width", img2.width - 10);


    }, 200);
        }
it wouldnt work it would just enlarge and stop

Comment: You stop enlarging because you have an `if..else` to test the image size and decide what to do.

Comment: it wont get smaller

Comment: You’d need to “remember which way you’re going”, yes. Have an additional external variable like `direction = 'smaller'`. Use the `if..else` to flip that to `larger` at the right time. Then enlarge or shrink based on that.

Comment: can you give an example please or a soultion to what could work here

Answer (score 2):

The following is a self-explanatory example of how to do it with a single interval. Keep track of the size and sign with a persistent variable (outside interval handler). Setup min, max, step and interval as needed.

```js
const div = document.getElementById('div');

const min = 100;
const max = 140;
const step = 10;
const interval = 200;

(() => {
  let sign = 1;
  let size = min;
  
  const handler = () => {
    sign = size >= min && size <= max ? sign : (sign * -1);
    size = size + step * sign;
    
    div.style.height = `${size}px`;
    div.style.width = `${size}px`;
  };
  
  setInterval(handler, interval);
})();
```

```css
#div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id='div'></span>
```

Comment: i changed it like you told me to but it still doesnt work only enlarges , never stops

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*** Your Example

setInterval(function () {
    var check = true; // Being within the interval, you are constantly defining true, it will never stop expanding.
    var img2 = document.getElementById('img2'); // You don't need to constantly search for the item.
    var imgW = img2.width;
    if (check)
        img2.style.width = (imgW + 20) + "px";
    else
        img2.style.width = (imgW - 20) + "px";
    if (imgW  >= 240 || imgW  <200) // You have to check with the new value.
        check = false; // You do not have to change it to false, you have to invert it, if it is true it goes to false and if it is false it goes to true


}, 200); // 200 is not 2 seconds, it is 0.2 seconds
  }
****/

var check = true;
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
setInterval(()=>{

  var imgW = img2.width;

  if( check ){
    img2.style.width = (imgW + 20) + "px";
  }else{
    img2.style.width = (imgW - 20) + "px";
  }

  if( img2.width > 240 || img2.width < 200 ){
    check  = !check  ;
  }

}, 200) // I leave it in 0.2 seconds
```

```html
<img id="img2" style="width:200px; height:200px;border:1px solid" />
```

Comment: If it works, I have taken your example and corrected it, read the notes to understand the bugs. I like Ernesto Stifano's solution but you have a very basic level to understand it.